# PowerShell: Getting AADSTS500014 error while trying to connect to Exchange Online

Tags: azure, powershell, office365

PowerShell: Getting AADSTS500014 error while trying to connect to Exchange Online

```
$admin="admin@M365x121212.onmicrosoft.com"
$adminPassword="xxxxxxxxxxx" 
$cred = [Management.Automation.PSCredential]::new($admin, $(ConvertTo-SecureString -Force -AsPlainText -String $adminPassword))

Import-Module ExchangeOnlineManagement
Connect-ExchangeOnline -Credential $cred  -ShowProgress $true
```

New-ExoPSSession : AADSTS500014: The service principal for resource 'https://outlook.office365.com' is disabled.  This indicate that a subscription within the tenant has lapsed, or that the administrator for this tenant has disabled the application, preventing tokens from being issued
for it.

Answer (score 1):

to resolve AADSTS500014 error:

1. Log into [portal office](https://portal.office.com)
2. Select Azure Active Directory
3. Select 'Enterprise applications' => 'Office 365 Exchange Online' => Properties
4. Select "Enabled for users to sign-in" and click Save button