# Cannot access Azure Marketplace

Tags: azure, azure-marketplace

I have a problem accessing the Azure Marketplace, when I click I get the following error:

"errorMessage": "AADSTS500014: The service principal for resource 'a0e1e353-1a3e-42cf-a8ea-3a9746eec58c' is disabled. This indicate that a subscription within the tenant has lapsed, or that the administrator for this tenant has disabled the application, preventing tokens from being issued for it.\r\nTrace ID: 036412b9-b388-4fdd-bf70-cdec70851b00\r\nCorrelation ID: ad7f449c-f8b3-4809-9925-e8de5e34cd02\r\nTimestamp: 2022-06-23 16:00:41Z"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> The error message says that either the tenant's subscription has expired or that the tenant's administrator has disabled the application, preventing the tokens from being issued for this process.

***Try the below steps to resolve the issue:***

- Firstly, Login to azure portal
- Then, click `Azure Active Directory` (AAD)
- Click-on  `Enterprise applications`  ->  `ALL APPLICATIONS`  ->  `AzureMarketplace`
- Then click  `Properties`
- Select  `Enabled for users to sign-in`
- Then click  `Save button`

*Below screenshots for the above procedure:*
[image]

Re-check this below option,
*Select the `Properties` -> `Enable for user to sign-in`.*
[image]

Make sure the subscription is still active and the application is not disabled for the above process.

***References:***

https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msteams/forum/all/error-code-aadsts500014-resource/fd7a1780-b5a1-4fc7-9dfc-209af811ae83

https://stackoverflow.com/a/67169672/18935775

Comment: It worked!

Thank you very much for your support. I cleared the filters and searched the app by ID and found it as Microsoft AppSource.